# Upload PDF file to mysql BLOB by using java.sql.PreparedStatement without corruption

Tags: java, mysql, sql, blob, prepared-statement

I tried to uplad a pdf file using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` to `mysql` Blob field using the following code.

```
        File inFile = new File("Path+BLOCK.pdf");
        byte[] b = new byte[(int)inFile.length()];

        PreparedStatement psmnt = (PreparedStatement) 
        con.prepareStatement("INSERT  INTO 
                        2012DOC (SRNO,DOCUMENT) 
                       VALUES  (?,?)"
                      );   //con is java.sql.Connection object
        psmnt.setString(1, "1200021");
        psmnt.setBytes(2, b);
        psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

This code executes without error and database shows blob content, but when I try to retrieve the file using the below code it gives a corrupt file which doesn't open.

```
ResultSet rs=con.Execute("SELECT DOCUMENT FROM 2012DOC");
rs.next();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=kjsahkjd.pdf");

java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob("DOCUMENT");
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
int length = (int) blob.length();
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

servletOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
servletOutputStream.flush();
servletOutputStream.close();
```

It outputs the file with same size as the original,but the file doesn't open.
The `pdf` reader is fired but cannot open the file and gives an error 'the file was either damaged or not supported file type'

Comment: I also had this kind of problems. Can you specify *doesn't open*? The PDF reader is fired but it cannot display the file? Or the browser doesn't end the download?

Comment: The pdf reader is fired but it cannot open the file. The reader gives an error 'the file was either damaged or not supported file type'

Comment: Without a reproducible test case, we can only try to guess to trim the problem down. I think your first attempt should be comparing the original file and the database content, to see if they really are binary equal. The driver is the official MySQL Connector/J, isn't it?

Comment: Also, instead of reading the content of the file in memory, you'd better use `PreparedStatement.setBlob(int, InputStream)`. According to the docs, `setBytes` uses `(LONG)VARBINARY`

Comment: @Raffaele, I found a way for that, using `setBinaryStream`... Posted the answer for other's reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh...After a little debugging I found the code that uploads is troublesome, and finally got the right way to do it.

Here is what I did...I'm posting it so that others with same problem can solve it

After Converting the `java.io.File` to `java.io.FileInputStream`

```
FileInputStream io = new FileInputStream(inFile);
```

Set the BLOB field using `psmnt.setBinaryStream()`

```
psmnt.setBinaryStream(3,  (InputStream)io,(int)inFile.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

remove " `java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob("DOCUMENT");` "

and don't initialize length i.e instead of

```
int length = (int) blob.length();
```

just write

```
int length;
```

then it downloads file successfully .. enjoy :)